# ttfb is very high for symfony2 php project

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I have xampp apache runnnig on my windows 8, 64 bit laptop. With symfony 2, the TTFB is about 4 sec, on prod, for every server response and about 8-10 secs on dev. I have no idea how to reduce this to under 1 sec. It is not possible to work with such latency.

To isolate the issue I did the following
1. localhost/xampp/ loads very fast (within 1 sec)
2. localhost/ims/web/test.php loads immediately. ims is the symfony2 project. The test.php has

Please tell me how to reduce the TTFB. It does seem to be an apache issue.

Comment: Did you check where is the bottleneck in the profiler timeline?

Comment: I am doing web development after a very long time. From the profiler timeline I cant see the evidence that I see in the chrome dev app timeline. Please advise what all things can I check.

Comment: It seem to be Symfony/component/security/http/firewall  and the controller; these two take 80% of the time. Still can't tell if the firewall is responsible for high TTFB

Answer (score 0):

If the firewall is using database for authenticate users maybe the bottleneck is in the database connection itself. Look at this link http://12wiki.blogspot.com/2012/11/why-does-symfony-2-firewall-take-so.html. Changing `database_host` from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` solved the problem.

Comment: This is the result of a small ajax query using GET.              Connection Setup  TIME
Stalled 
​
1.571 ms
DNS Lookup 
​
0.898 ms
Initial connection 
​
1.025 ms
Request/Response  TIME
Request sent 
​
2.019 ms
Waiting (TTFB) 
​
2.07 s
Content Download 
​
1.192 ms.<br><br> I hace a very high TFTB of 2000 ms compared to the 10 ms of actual work done.

Comment: I NEED SOME SERIOUS HELP HERE. I can't do ajax with this kind of slow response. There must be a solution to this. I really appreciate anyone giving a good clue.

Comment: One more difference I noted. All the assets in DEV takes longer (php, js, css and png). In PROD environment, only the php takes longer and everything else is superfast.

Comment: I followed suggestion on the following post to bring the ttfb a tad bit lower but not much. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854848/windows-7-php-symfony2-terribly-slow