# Deploy Simple Symfony application to Azure : Slow?

Tags: php, symfony, azure, azure-web-app-service

Last week, I tried to deploy a simple symfony app on azure.
I choose the plan app service B2 (2cores / 3.5Go RAM).
PHP Version : 5.6.

First it took forever to complete the composer install. (I tried to go on S3, it was a little faster but not very different).
So I tried to optimize the php config, opcache, realpath_cache_size...etc (xdebug already disabled).
I even tried to enable wincache, but with no real improvment.

So now my app is deployed, but it is too slow to be usable.
A simple php app/console (in dev mode) takes ~23secondes.
It seems to recreate the cache everytime. On my local unix environnment (similar specs), it takes 6seconds when the cache is cold and 500ms when the dev cache is warm.

[image: measure time php app/console dev mode]

I think that the main problem is a filesystem issue, because to remove the dev cache folder it takes 16 seconds.
On my local unix environnment, similar specs, it takes ~200ms to remove the same folder.

[image: measure time remove dev cache folder]

Like I said I tried S3 Plan with a small improvment but not enough to explain this slowness.
One thing weird, it's that if I rerun the command php app/console just after it finished, the command takes 5seconds to run (much better). But If rerun it 5seconds after it finished, it takes 23seconds.

I already tried these solutions (even if the environnment is different) :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17021255/6309878

**Update** : I tried to set the symfony app/cache folder to the local filesystem D:\local\cache, but no improvment, it may be worst.

Comment: Wondering if anyone saw fast thing made by micro***t.

Comment: @abdelwahid , since the issue is a bit hard to reproduce on our side, could you please share the web app's info with us via leveraging the approach that pointed out at https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly? Looking forward to having your feedback.

Comment: @abdelwahid, we are trying to dig into your site. And any updates, we will reply you in this questions.

Comment: @WillShao-MSFT Any news about your investigation ? Because I want to choose azure as a solution, but this slowness is a no go.

Comment: @abdelwahid, Could you please try Prasad's solution? Any update, please let us know.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below steps and let me know if it improves the performance -

1) In the wwwroot directory of your site, create a .user.ini file (if it doesn’t already exist) and add “wincache.fcenabled=0”.  This will disable Wincache.

2) Go to Azure Portal and go to the Application Settings for your app.  In the App Settings section, add “WEBSITES_DYNAMIC_CACHE” with a value of 1.

3) Restart the site.